# How do I get the n-th derivative of the function f(s)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

How do I get the n-th derivative of the function f(s)
The result of the n-th derivative is also shown in the picture
[image]     and the n-th derative
[image]

Comment: What you can do is to expand f[x] around s and then do the integral.

Comment: @ Daniel,  but if i execute the formula 
`HoldForm[f[s_] := 1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z]] ==  1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z]`
How to interpret the outcome ?

Comment: You ask if  the pattern on the left hand side "f[s_]:= ..."  is equal to the expression on the right hand side: "- 1/(2Pi Integral[..])".  This is simlilar to e.g. "_ == q".

Comment: @ Daniel, i made a mistake with the question  ... but if i execute the formula :

`D[f[s]^n, {s, n}]`

How to interpret the outcome ?..partial derative , so the output shows the input again 
Conclusion : no general formula to  get on this way. 
Expand ..no experience with this : in a complex serie ?

Comment: Its a analytic function ...in complex analyse

Comment: You did not define "f" so you can not get a derivative and MMA simply returns the input

Comment: @janamdo Your definition of `f` does not make much sense as written, with the equal sign in there and wrapped in `HoldForm`. If this stems from a problem in copy/pasting code from Mathematica to here, then please take a look at [How to copy code from Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951). Please first focus on defining your function $f$, and then you could read up on `Series` to follow up on Daniel's suggestion to expand the expression in a series to accomplish what you want. More generally though, if you know the answer already, then why do you need to do this?

Comment: @MarcoB , i do want to learn Mathematica better. This the only advanced result that i have.
There is more to explore

Answer (score 5):

If we define `f` in a straightforward way, ignoring the complex analysis and just focusing on the calculus as in the OP, we see that `D[]` can find specific derivatives:

```
f[s_] = 1/(2 \[Pi] I) Integrate[g[z]/(z - s), z];

Table[D[f[s], {s, n}], {n, 5}]
```

> ```
> (*
> {  -((   I*Integrate[g[z]/(-s + z)^2, z]) /(2*Pi)), 
>    -((   I*Integrate[g[z]/(-s + z)^3, z]) / Pi), 
>    -(( 3*I*Integrate[g[z]/(-s + z)^4, z]) / Pi), 
>    -((12*I*Integrate[g[z]/(-s + z)^5, z]) / Pi), 
>    -((60*I*Integrate[g[z]/(-s + z)^6, z]) / Pi)}
> *)
> ```

However there is a bug in the general derivative:

```
D[f[s], {s, n}]
FullSimplify[%, n \[Element] Integers && n > 0]
Table[%, {n, 5}]
```

> ```
> (*
> -((I n! *
>   DifferenceRoot[
>    Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]},
>     {\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (s - z) \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0,
>      \[FormalY][0] == z (-s + z)^(-1) g[z]}]][n]) / (2π))
>                       ↑              <-- extra z from Integrate(?)
>      ↓                               <--
> -((I z (-s + z)^(-1 - n) n! g[z])/(2π))
>           ↓
> { -((   I z g[z]) /(2π (-s + z)^2)), <-- extra z in all results
>   -((   I z g[z]) / (π (-s + z)^3)), 
>   -(( 3 I z g[z]) / (π (-s + z)^4)), 
>   -((12 I z g[z]) / (π (-s + z)^5)), 
>   -((60 I z g[z]) / (π (-s + z)^6))}
> *)
> ```

There is a bug in `Integrate` when integrating `DifferenceRoot` objects that depend on the variable of integration:

Substitute `n -> 3` after integration:

```
Integrate[
  DifferenceRoot[
    Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]},
     {\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (z + 1) \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0,
      \[FormalY][0] == 1}]
    ][n], 
  z] /. n -> 3
```

> ```
> (*  -(z/(1 + z)^3)  *)
> ```

Substitute `n -> 3` before integration:

```
Integrate[
 DifferenceRoot[
    Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]},
     {\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (z + 1) \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0,
      \[FormalY][0] == 1}]
    ][n] /. n -> 3, 
 z]
```

> ```
> (*  1/(2 (1 + z)^2)  *)
> ```

*Edit update:*

By the way, it works if we differentiate the integrand directly $n$ times:

```
1/(2 Pi I) Integrate[D[g[z]/(z - s), {s, n}], z]
FullSimplify[%, n > 0 && n \[Element] Integers]
```

> ```
> (*
> -((I*(-1)^n*FactorialPower[-1, n]*
>          Integrate[(-s + z)^(-1 - n)*g[z], z])/(2*Pi))
>
> -((I*n!*Integrate[(-s + z)^(-1 - n)*g[z], z])/(2*Pi))
> *)
> ```

Comment: Reported as [CASE:4902127].

Comment: It seems that i did not defined the function properly? 
f[s_] := ............ is not good?

Comment: @janamdo The code in your comment looks like a good start, but the code in the question starts like `HoldForm[f[s_] := ...`, which out is not good,  as someone has pointed. Perhaps you had seen `HoldPattern[f[s_]] :=...` (note how many `[` and `]` there are). This form would work, too, but shouldn't be needed. (If it is needed, you're probably doing something wrong.)

Comment: yes this is the right answer.
`-((I*n!*Integrate[(-s + z)^(-1 - n)*g[z], z])/(2*Pi))`
Only the way to get this result is not straight forward for me ( i am not satisfied, because i can do it now not by myself )
I should integrate the complex expression , because that doesn't matter for Mathematica i presume